# Why does this hostent cause a segfault?

Tags: c, network-programming, hostent

```
struct hostent *hostName;

struct in_addr ipv4addr;

inet_pton(AF_INET, inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), &ipv4addr);

hostName = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof(ipv4addr), AF_INET);

printf("Host name: %s\n", hostName->h_name);
```

It segfaults on the last line. I looked up proper use of hostent, and the msdn docs show it being used EXACTLY like this. What would cause the segfault?

Comment: Maybe gethostbyaddre resturns NULL and dereferencing NULL causes a segfault; or hostName->h_name is NULL and then printf()'ing NULL segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gethostbyaddr()` function returns `NULL` in the case of an error, and I don't see you checking for that in your code.  Attempting to dereference a `NULL` pointer would cause a segfault.

You need something like:

```
if (hostName == NULL) {
  printf("There was an error!\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

You may be able to use the `herror()` function to print out the actual error encountered by the resolver (although the man page indicates that `herror()` is obsolete).